# WiX: Simple way to prompt user to install .NET pre-requisite

Tags: wix

I currently have a working .msi built with WiX that has a user interface I'm quite happy with. The only thing missing is to detect for missing .NET 4.5 and either:

- Install it using an embedded web setup, or
- Direct the user to the .NET 4.5 download

The previous Setup and Deployment project I was using simply added it as a LaunchCondition with a URL and that worked well enough.

How can I add this to the WiX installer without resorting to a bootstrapper. From what I can tell using a bootstrapper like burn would require re-implementing a new user interface, likewise a tool like dotNetInstaller would also introduce a new UI.

If I can have the bootstrapper not implement it's own UI but trigger the .NET installation then open the msi's current user interface that would also work for me.

Comment: Did you come across this: http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wixnetfxextension.htm

Comment: Yes, I'm already detecting the presence/non-presence of .NET 4.5 but what I'd like to do is prompt the user to download it - or even better include and run the web installer for them - without having to use a bootstrapper/bundle since that removes the UI my installer (msi) currently has.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38194858/1803823

Answer (score 1):

I also wanted to keep the UI from the MSI so I added this code to start an exe installer for hardware keys. I know it goes against MSI Best Practices but this is the only one I intend on breaking. Hope this helps.

```
<Property Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[#myapplication.exe]" />
<CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixShellExec" Impersonate="yes" />
```

I then ran the custom action from a button click. You could spawn an error dialog with a download button on it and link it via that. Not very elegant at all but it works for me and my company as a work around..:)

EDIT: you could also use this code from a button click to launch the URL for the download, the `Value` attribute having the full hyperlink.

Comment: Thank you, it's a little gem, I run two hardware key exe's and also run a separate URL and it works for all three..:)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I went with something else but glad people found it useful :)

Comment: No problem, I too used a custom action until I found this. Trying to cut down on custom actions unless they are really needed so this is a good workaround. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I ended up using... hasn't been through full testing yet!

Product.wxs:

```
    ...
    <!-- custom actions -->
    <InstallUISequence> <!-- .NET dialog runs only in UI mode and we skip it on the wrong platform so platform condition test is triggered later -->
      <?if $(var.Platform) = x64 ?>
      <Custom Action="InstallCA" Before="LaunchConditions">(NOT REMOVE~="ALL") AND NOT (Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK45) AND VersionNT64</Custom>
      <?elseif $(var.Platform) = x86 ?>
      <Custom Action="InstallCA" Before="LaunchConditions">(NOT REMOVE~="ALL") AND NOT (Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK45) AND NOT VersionNT64</Custom>
      <?endif?>
    </InstallUISequence>
  </Product> <!-- end product -->

  <Fragment>
    <Binary Id="WiXCustomActions" SourceFile="$(var.WiXCustomActions.TargetDir)$(var.WiXCustomActions.TargetName).CA.dll" />
    <CustomAction Id="InstallCA" BinaryKey="WiXCustomActions" DllEntry="DotNetCheck" Execute="firstSequence" />
  </Fragment>
```

And the custom action (in a C# class library):

```
    [CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult DotNetCheck(Session session)
    {
        try
        {
            MessageBoxResult result = System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(
                "This application requires that .NET Framework 4.5 is installed." + Environment.NewLine
                + "Would you like to open the Microsoft download page for" + Environment.NewLine + ".NET Framework 4.5?",
                ".NET Framework 4.5 is missing",
                MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Information, MessageBoxResult.No, MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly);
            switch (result)
            {
                case MessageBoxResult.Yes:
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=245484");
                    break;
            } //else just finish
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            session.Log("Error. " + ex.Message);
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Error:" + ex.Message);
        }
        return ActionResult.SkipRemainingActions;
    }
```

It works good enough for me...

Answer (score 0):

And one important things, when you will be creating this DLL lib

> And the custom action (in a C# class library):

Need to add next References:

```
using WixSharp    
using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller
using System.Windows.Forms
```

also replace "MessegeBoxResult" to "DialogResult" and MessegeBox should get from class System.Windows.Forms